# @Bean method, allthough in different classes, clashes Beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-batch, javabeans

Suppose I have two config classes that are the same, expect from a @Value tag, which is mapped to the corresponding property. As the @Bean annotated methods of this classes are equally named, I'm getting clashes. It doesn't seem to work neither using @Scope("prototype") nor calling the bean() method using "this".

I need all of the methods to be @Beans, so they can be managed by the spring context.

As both methods need to be configured with ClassA and ClassB properties, inheritance is not a good approach neitherdynamically injecting beans to context using a factory / register.

I know how to solve this changing bean() name to beanA() and beanB() but it has to exists a cleaner solution.

I need a cleaner solution to avoid code repetition. Nowadays if a new setter is added to ComplexObject, I have to modify classA and ClassB. Imagine having 100 Classes..that would be a lot of work.

```
@Configuration
public class ClassA{
....

@Value("${some-config.important-property}")
private String importantPropertyOnlyExistingInThisClass;

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public ComplexObject bean(){

   ComplexObject o = new ComplexObject();

    o.setImportantProp(this.importantPropertyOnlyExistingInThisClass)

    return o;
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public AnotherComplexObject beanUsingBean(){
    AnotherComplexObject aO = new AnotherComplexObject();

    ao.setComplexObject(bean())

    return aO;
}

}


@Configuration
public class ClassB{
....

@Value("${another-config.important-property}")
private String importantPropertyOnlyExistingInThisClass;


@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public ComplexObject bean(){

    ComplexObject o = new ComplexObject();

    o.setImportantProp(this.importantPropertyOnlyExistingInThisClass)

    return o;
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public AnotherComplexObject beanUsingBean(){
    AnotherComplexObject aO = new AnotherComplexObject();

    ao.setComplexObject(bean())

    return aO;
}

}
```

I would expect to have an easier way to initialize similar beans using java config.

Comment: Have you ever encountered `@Bean(name="nameMeDifferent")` or `@Qualifier("imADifferentBean")`. Hope this post would help you. [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/inject-bean-by-name.html)

Comment: That's hardcoding. Won't help either

Comment: You have to understand that bean names are unique to context scope not class scope. You cannot have two beans with same name in same application context.

Comment: Got that, but I was hoping to get the bean name defined on runtime.